# Error 1236 in MySQL GTID Slave due to mistaken 'reset master' on MySQL 5.7 GTID master

Tags: mysql, replication, gtid

Sequence of events:

1. Disabled binary logs in MySQL 8 slave with the following relevant parameters in `mysqld.cnf`:

```
log-replica-updates = OFF
gtid-mode = ON
enforce-gtid-consistency = ON
master-info-repository = TABLE
relay-log-info-repository = TABLE
relay_log_recovery = ON
sync-master-info = 1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
sync_binlog = 0
slave-preserve-commit-order = ON
# binlog_expire_logs_seconds    = 2592000
#max_binlog_size   = 100M
```

2. Did not purge binary logs before disabling binary
   logging in MySQL 8 Slave
3. re-enabled binary logging by uncommenting:

```
# binlog_expire_logs_seconds    = 2592000
# max_binlog_size   = 100M
```

and commenting:

```
disable-log-bin
```

and instead of executing `reset master` in MySQL 8 slave,
mistakenly executed the command `reset master`
on MySQL 5.7 master while replication is running

4. There was no backup of binary logs in master
5. Purged and re-installed the MySQL 8 slave, restored the backup (executed on master:

```
mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases --flush-logs \
 --single-transaction --routines --triggers --events \
 --master-data=2 > alldbs.sql
```

6. Reconfigured GTID replication using MySQL master 5.7
   and MySQL slave 8.0.

Relevant parameters from the MySQL 5.7 master `mysqld.cnf`:

```
binlog-format = ROW
log-slave-updates = ON
gtid-mode = ON
enforce-gtid-consistency = ON
master-info-repository = TABLE
relay-log-info-repository = TABLE
sync-master-info = 1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
sync_binlog = 1
binlog-transaction-dependency-tracking = COMMIT_ORDER
```

7. Observed an error:

> 1236: Last_IO_Error: Got fatal error 1236 from master when reading data from binary log: 'Slave has more GTIDs than the master has, using the master's SERVER_UUID. This may indicate that the end of the binary log was truncated or that the last binary log file was lost, e.g., after a power or disk failure when sync_binlog != 1.
>
> The master may or may not have rolled back transactions that were already replicated to the slave.
>
> Suggest to replicate any transactions that master has rolled back
> from slave to master,
> and/or commit empty transactions on master to account
> for transactions that have been

How to reconfigure GTID replication?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I executed 'reset master' in **master** in stead of **slave** to purge binary logs. All binary logs in master are reset now. Replication is broken. Please help me to get replication back on track.

Comment: @Marcello Miorelli, Please let me know what additional details you need for getting the broken replication back on track

Comment: @SarmaMV please add SHOW MASTER STATUS, current SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G and also check you GTIDS from your backup, with something like this:
grep -i "gtid_purged" alldbs.sql | head -1

Answer (score 0):

Configured replication with steps below:

1. Purged and reinstalled MySQL 8 in slave
2. Enabled binary logging with:

```
   binlog_expire_logs_seconds = 86400
   log-replica-updates = OFF
```

3. Took back-up from master:

```
   mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases --flush-logs --single-transaction \
    --routines    --triggers --events --master-data=2 > alldbs-23Oct2022
```

4. restored back-up on slave
5. started replication:

```
   CHANGE REPLICATION SOURCE TO SOURCE_HOST="w.x.y.z", 
    SOURCE_USER="username", SOURCE_PASSWORD="Password",   
    SOURCE_AUTO_POSITION=1;
```

Comment: I had observed that a slave thread was running in the master with itself as slave  

Steps I had taken before Configuring the replication on the slave mentioned in Answer I had posted:  

Executed the following on master:  

stop slave;  

reset slave;  

reset slave all;